# XGBoost and count:poisson

Tags: xgboost, poisson

The [XGBoost library](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parameter.html) lists `count:poisson` as one of its learning task parameters. The official documentation is pretty limited and only says:

> *Poisson regression for count data, output mean of Poisson distribution*

Does anybody know a bit more about how this is calculated, as the above is quite confusing?

Alternatively, I've been trying to locate in the [XGBoost GitHub repo](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost) the source code where `count:poisson` is defined, but to no avail. Does anybody know where I can locate this please? Aka, the specific file that details how this is calculated?